# undefined method PDO lastInsertId

Tags: php, database, pdo, lastinsertid

I have an insert query, and I want to get the ID from the table. I have been searching, and I found lastInsertId() for PDO. When I want to use it, I get PHP errors.

This is my code:

```
$db = new database();
$naam = $db->quoteQuery($_POST['naam']);
$barcode = $db->quoteQuery($_POST['barcode']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO products(name, barcode) VALUES (".$name.",".$barcode.")";
$results = $db->executeQuery($sql);
$lastid = $results->lastInsertId();
```

But this gives an error, this one:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId() in /home/onlineweuh/domains/onlinewebapps.nl/public_html/vsb/admin/add-product.class.php on line 297
```

My database class:

```
    class database 
{
    private $handleDB;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = ;
        $user = ;
        $database = ;
        $password = ;
        try
        {
            $this->handleDB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $password);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print_r($e);
        }

        $this->handleDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    }
```

I hope someone can help me solve it, I want the ID which is given at the insert Query.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You get the lastinsertid from the PDO object and not your results object.

Try `$db->lastInsertId()`

edit below.

Your database class is encapsulating your handleDB / PDO object.  Since the handleDB variable is private, you cannot access this outside your class.  You would need to either make it public like so;

```
class database 
{
    public $handleDB;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = 'removed';
        $user = 'removed';
        $database = 'removed';
        $password = 'removed';
        try
        {
            $this->handleDB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $password);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print_r($e);
        }

        $this->handleDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    }

}
```

Now you can call `$db->handleDB->lastInsertId();`

Or you could expose the `handleDB->lastInsertId()` as a function like:

```
class database 
{
    private $handleDB;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $host = 'remove';
        $user = 'removed';
        $database = 'removed';
        $password = 'removed';
        try
        {
            $this->handleDB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $user, $password);
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            print_r($e);
        }

        $this->handleDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    }

    public function lastInsertId(){
        return $this->handleDB->lastInsertId();
    }

}
```

You would call using `$db->lastInsertId();`

Comment: Then I'm getting the error: Call to undefined method database::lastInsertId()

Comment: You need to call directly the new metod:

    $results = $db->executeQuery($sql);
    $lastid = $db->lastInsertId();

Answer (score 17):

`lastInsertId` is a method of `PDO`, not `PDOStatement`. Therefore:

```
$db->lastInsertId();
```

Comment: Then I'm getting the error: Call to undefined method database::lastInsertId()

Comment: Does `database` extend `PDO`? What PHP version are you on?

Comment: My PHP version is: 5.2.12. I have placed my PHP database class in the begin post.

Comment: Well, since `database` doesn't extend `PDO`, it obviously doesn't have a method `lastInsertId` either. You need to pass that call through to your `$handleDB` `PDO` object, or you need to return that object so your code can call `lastInsertId` on it.

Answer (score 0):

your database class needs to be a subclass of PDO by extending PDO

```
class database extends PDO
```

that way all the methods in PDO are available to your subclass.